# Android- Crash related to thread

Tags: android, qt, crash

I get this report from Google play. I'm developing application using Qt.
So would anyone mind to give me some suggestions?

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/klteduosxx/klte:5.0/LRX21T/G900FDXXU1BOD1:user/release-keys'
Revision: '14'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 9031, tid: 16456, name: QtThread  >>> org.qtproject.myapplication <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x9a500000
    r0 9a4fff00  r1 00000100  r2 00000000  r3 00000120
    r4 9a4ffffc  r5 00000000  r6 00000000  r7 aeee1340
    r8 9a4a4220  r9 00000124  sl 00000000  fp 00000000
    ip aeee0e40  sp 9c829280  lr 9c3d7965  pc 9c3d68c6  cpsr 800b0030

backtrace:
    #00 pc 001d28c6  /data/app/org.qtproject.myapplication-1/lib/arm/libQt5Gui.so
    #01 pc 001d3961  /data/app/org.qtproject.myapplication-1/lib/arm/libQt5Gui.so
    #02 pc 000cd671  /data/app/org.qtproject.myapplication-1/lib/arm/libQt5Gui.so (QImage::smoothScaled(int, int) const+88)
    #03 pc 000cd897  /data/app/org.qtproject.myapplication-1/lib/arm/libQt5Gui.so (QImage::transformed(QTransform const&, Qt::TransformationMode) const+326)
    #04 pc 000e442d  /data/app/org.qtproject.myapplication-1/lib/arm/libQt5Gui.so (QPlatformPixmap::transformed(QTransform const&, Qt::TransformationMode) const+28)
    #05 pc 000dfa21  /data/app/org.qtproject.myapplication-1/lib/arm/libQt5Gui.so (QPixmap::transformed(QTransform const&, Qt::TransformationMode) const+52)
    #06 pc 000dfae5  /data/app/org.qtproject.myapplication-1/lib/arm/libQt5Gui.so (QPixmap::scaled(QSize const&, Qt::AspectRatioMode, Qt::TransformationMode) const+188)
    #07 pc 000f8c1f  /data/app/org.qtproject.myapplication-1/lib/arm/libNavaMessenger.so (CGlobalZone::loadSmileyImages(int)+118)
    #08 pc 0009f1ff  /data/app/org.qtproject.myapplication-1/lib/arm/libNavaMessenger.so (main+3814)
    #09 pc 00019989  /data/data/org.qtproject.myapplication/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so
    #10 pc 000137bb  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+30)
    #11 pc 0001189b  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your trying paint into QPixmap in non-gui thread. But:

> Because QImage is a QPaintDevice subclass, QPainter can be used to draw directly onto images. When using QPainter on a QImage, the painting can be performed in another thread than the current GUI thread.

From [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#details)

Therefore, use QImage instead.